# Asp.net Textbox replacement or better design

Tags: asp.net

Can someone direct me to a good Textbox replacement or css design for the standart one.
I think the regular one is boring but functioning well. I just need to make it look nicer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply CSS on MarkUp like this.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" />
```

CSS

.textbox{
    behavior: url(border-radius.htc);

```
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
padding: 6px 6px 4px;
box-shadow: 2px 3px 2px #eee;
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 2px #eee;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 2px #eee;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left 15, from(#FFFFFF), color-stop(4%, #f4f4f4), to(#FFFFFF));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #FFFFFF, #f4f4f4 1px, #FFFFFF 15px);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#f4f4f4');
```

}

Before that download http://curved-corner.googlecode.com/files/border-radius.htc and place it in the same folder the CSS resides.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/YqRCU/2/

Comment: is it just me or the regular textbox looks like the styled one exactly?

Comment: no i'd say that will be your IE browser :) try webkit or firefox

Comment: Ahh in chrome it looks very nice. Does it means that no IE support?

Comment: updated answer. check now. now bg gradient will be there. for curvce and shadow you need the htc

Answer (score 1):

In the resulting HTML page TextBox is rendered as a standard `input` element:

```
<input type="text" />
```

So, you may apply any sort of CSS styling for it, there is no need for another control. As for CSS example, you may start from [here](http://designshack.co.uk/tutorials/10-css-form-examples) to get some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/533eV/1/ maybe it is to simple, but you could play with shadows, or change colors ect.

Answer (score 0):

I now saw this website which shows many nice text inputs (check #44 out):
**http://html-generator.weebly.com/css-textbox-style.html**